# hbase delete records based on portion of id

Tags: java, hbase

I would like to know if it is possible to delete records from a table based on the id of the row. For example I created a table named 'hbase_test' with the family 'cmmnttest' and column 'cmmntpost' with the ids created as follows:

```
'99.abcdefghijkil'
'99.oiuerwrerwwre'
```

I need to find all rows that have id starting with '99' and delete them. This is a combination of a client id '99' and the value of the record.

I found the following but not sure if it applies here:

To delete a cell from ‘t1′ at row ‘r1′ under column ‘c1′
marked with the time ‘ts1′, do:
hbase> delete ‘t1′, ‘r1′, ‘c1′, ts1

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you cannot do that in the HBase shell, but you can easily do it with the Java API, you'll just have to create a scanner providing "99." as start rowkey and "100." as stop rowkey, iterate all the results and delete them in batches:

```
Configuration conf           = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HTable table                 = new HTable(conf, "myTable");
ArrayList<Delete> deleteList = new ArrayList<Delete>();
int maxDeletesPerBatch       = 1000;
Scan scan                    = new Scan( "99.".getBytes(), "100.".getBytes()); // Separator used to avoid targeting "999", "9999", "99999" ...
scan.setCaching(maxDeletesPerBatch); // Get the scanner results in batches
ResultScanner scanner        = table.getScanner(scan);
try {
    for (Result result : scanner) {
        deleteList.add(new Delete(result.getRow()));
        if (deleteList.size() == maxDeletesPerBatch) {
            // Max deletes reached, flush deletes and clear the list
            table.delete(deleteList);
            deleteList.clear();
        }
    }
} finally {
    scanner.close();
    if (deleteList.size() > 0) {
        // Flush remaining deletes
        table.delete(deleteList);
    }
    table.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I will give it a try and report back.