# Delete Hbase entries based on partial key(Suffix) using Java API

Tags: java, hbase

Can we delete rows based on suffix of row key? Something which is opposite of PrefixFilter.

My rowkey is like?

```
07/08/2016_99
08/08/2016_99
09/08/2016_99
```

and i want to delete all entries ending with 99.

Some thing like this [hbase delete records based on portion of id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843407/hbase-delete-records-based-on-portion-of-id) but with suffix.

Answer (score 0):

**Use** `RegexStringComparator` . The code snippet below can be a simple example.

```
    String expr = "^.*99$";
    int flag = Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL;;
    RegexStringComparator.EngineType engineType = RegexStringComparator.EngineType.JAVA;

    RowFilter rowFilter = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
            new RegexStringComparator(expr, flag, engineType));
```